# Sort text file of blocks

Tags: sorting, plaintext

There are plenty of tools that will sort a text file on the assumption that the unit of interest is the line, but are there any that work on blocks?

Example:

```
name = Mercury
order = 1
mass = 0.06

name = Venus
order = 2
mass = 0.82

name = Earth
order = 3
mass = 1
```

Is there a tool that would sort the list of planets optionally by name, mass or order from the sun, taking as input and producing as output a text file with each record being a block like the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For files that fit into memory you could use Perl, you can define the input record separator.

```
 perl -e '$/="\n\n"; print sort <>' t.txt
```

If the file is too big for memory but you have an equal amount of free disk space, you can do a three step sort:

- use perl to merge lines of each record
- sort
- use perl to split lines of each record

To sort by the value of one of the attributes, I would read the data into a suitable data structure such as an array of hashes [AoH](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#ARRAYS-OF-HASHES) and define a comparator as described in [`perldoc -f sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html)

Alternatively I would

- Use perl to convert to CSV of values only
- sort
- Use perl to convert CSV back to multiline records with name=value pairs

It would probably be best to do the whole job in Perl.

*Other programming languages are available.*